# My sql SELECT statement JOIN on three tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I tried performing join on three tables but i'm struck

Here where condition would be id = 0 and test =0 and data =0

Each table will have different no of columns

I want to select a,b,c in al three tables.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Show the SQL code you have tried and describe what you're stuck with.

Comment: What query you've written can you post here?

Comment: actually..i dont see any tables.  where are the table names?

Comment: is there any relation with these 3 tables?

Comment: @sujal: Relation is id,test,data

Comment: where condition for id=0?? why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure about the relationship among these tables

Comment: @sujal:It is just an example,id can be any thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a Mysql SELECT on 3 tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388883/how-to-do-a-mysql-select-on-3-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertsand the question, which to be honest I don't, are you looking for a union?

```
select a,b,c,0 as e,0 as f, test,data from table1
union
select a,b,c,e,f, test,data from table2
union
select a,b,c,0 as e,0 as f, test,data from table3
```

**edit** included e and f

**edit2** You will need to add the where clause before each union

```
select a,b,c,0 as e,0 as f, test,data from table1
  where test= 1 and data =1 and id =0
union
select a,b,c,e,f, test,data from table2
  where test= 1 and data =1 and id =0
union
select a,b,c,0 as e,0 as f, test,data from table3
  where test= 1 and data =1 and id =0
```

Comment: in this case you can select all the columns while using same approach and manipulate the desire columns on your server side script.

Comment: See edit, have included e and f, For table1 and table3 I am just returning 0

Comment: @Rippo:I got it working,now how do i add where test= 1 and data =1 and id =0.

Comment: If this has helped then please vote me up and mark answer as accepted, thanks. You may want to accept some more of your answers as answered as some people won't help you in future with a low rate.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any relation in your table so how can you use join? if you just want to display a,b and c records from all tables then u can use UNION.

```
select a,b,c from tbl_name1
UNION
select a,b,c from tbl_name2
UNION
select a,b,c from tbl_name3
```

Comment: @sujal - This is a direct copy of my answer!