# PHP concat a word to mysql query

Tags: php

I have a query

```
"select * from test";
```

I have to add UNION after test

```
"select * from test union"
```

It is not concat.

How do I add union to the query?

**update**

```
select * from x where id = "2" union select * from y where id = "2" union select * from z where id = "2"
select * from x where id = "3" union select * from y where id = "3" union select * from z where id = "3"
```

See select statement id = 3 ,union is missing. Now,i've to add this union in the query to execute and remove last extra union and pass the query to mysql_query() function.

Comment: @Jon:i've added the query to the question.what code do you want?

Comment: "It is not concat" is not enough information. I 'm trying to say that this question is not well specified and you should provide more data (it will probably be downvoted/closed if you do not, and if not you will not get good answers).

Comment: This is apparently a terrific database design. What are these tables? Why do you think you need union here?

Comment: @Your Common Sense:Check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394300/my-sql-select-statement-join-on-three-tables

Comment: What are these tables? What is the tables structure? Why do you think you need 3, not one?

Comment: @Your Common Sense:there are three tables,save different things.In that image,3 rows are 3 tables,it is an example table.

Comment: what image you are talking about? Can't you just describe these tables? At the moment you are wasting other people's time with pointless question.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: select * from x union select * from y union select * from z union.I've to remove union which is after z.above query is example,there can any no of select statement ,from that ,i've to remove last line union word from the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$var1 = "Select * from test";
$vart2 = "union";
$vart3  =  var1." ".var2;
echo $var3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here bud what UNION does is combine the results of 2 separate SELECT queries

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
```

or

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
```

for duplicates use UNION ALL

**EDIT:**

Instead of using this use OUTER JOINS
LEFT JOIN

They are much better. and give you exact results wait i will build a query for you.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT * FROM tablename_1 temp_name_1 
LEFT JOIN tablename_2 temp_name_2 ON temp_name_1.id=temp_name_2.id 
LEFT JOIN tablename_3 temp_name_3 ON temp_name_1.id=temp_name_3.id 
WHERE temp_name_1.id = "2"
```

where tablename_1 is x, tablename_2 is y, tablename_3 is y

and temp_name_1, temp_name_2, temp_name_3 are the names what ever you like. these are temp names so you can remove the temp_name_? and can use the original name of the table.

**EDIT:**

Use this to join your select statements:

```
$string = "";
$string .= (!empty($string)?" UNION ":" ")."Your query here";
```

whether in loop or in if else if's

Comment: :See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394300/my-sql-select-statement-join-on-three-tables ,is this not correct? i was getting the required o/p.

Comment: :What are those three tables.can you make it clear?

Comment: :Pls,check my link ,to under stand my table structure.

Comment: i got the idea of what you want. you want to get the associated data for the id from all three tables. This is the best solution for this as the data for a single id is give in single row. check the query and test it in your program.

Comment: :Your query will not fetch,if a column is empty.I want all records which is also empty,that is why i used union all

Comment: No bud That's what `OUTER JOINS` for, they fetch the results even if the right tables are empty.

Comment: :Will outer join work on my sql,i do not think so.pls,give me a solution.select * from x union select * from y union select * from z union.I've to remove union which is after z.above query is example,there can any no of select statement ,from that ,i've to remove last line union word from the query

Comment: okh wait i will give you a solution. **so this is in a loop or normal if else's???** or something else?? check the edit

Comment: query is inside for loop or tell me ,how to remove that last union word,that will be a big favor.

Comment: check my edit init the variable which contains the sql query as empty. and then use the code. this will add a unoin after every query except the first one.

Comment: :Can you combine every thing and give me a query.You've many edit,m confused.pls,explain what that does?

Comment: See the last edit or provide me with the loop you r using

Comment: :Tell me what your code does?'

Comment: my code just adds the `UNION` before every query except the first one, so your code donot add the **last** `UNION` in the sql query

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  SELECT * FROM test
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM test1
```

Comment: Dilip Godhani gives your question answer

Comment: :I did not under stand his answer